# Angular 4 - Return HttpErrorResponse from interceptor

Tags: angular, error-handling, observable, interceptor

This in my interceptor

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(req)
      .catch(err => {
        if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
          this.errorControl(req, err.status);
          return Observable.throw(err);
        }
      });
  }
```

I need to catch the error sent from the server in my component since I have to act accordingly (404: return to last url, 400: show a message, etc). When I catch the error in the subscription to the observable I get this

```
"You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable."
```

but I need a HttpErrorResponse with its status, status text, etc.

Removing the interceptor solves my problem, but I need it for all the session stuff.

Comment: Could you post the content of your `errorControl(req, err.status)` function ?

Comment: Can you show the code that its actually causing the error? How are you catching the error in the subscription

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is this :

```
if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
  this.errorControl(req, err.status);
  return Observable.throw(err);
}
```

But I don't see an `else` anywhere !

This means you aren't returning the error when your error isn't an instance of `HttpErrorResponse`.

You should return an Observable in any case, not only when it suits you.

Comment: So you're telling me to throw the error no matter what? Anyway that doesn't completely solve my problem, in the case of, for example, a 400 status code error I still get the message above and not a HttpErrorResponse

Comment: Well, that's how an interceptor works ... You're supposed to pass the error (or the success !) through no matter what, and in your case, you don't. and you won't get an `undefined` error if you return the error in all cases, I'm pretty sure about that.

Comment: I now return the error outside of the conditional, if it gets to the catch it should send it no matter what its type is, but I still get the undefined thingy. I have many interceptors, this one beeing the last one, can my problem be caused because of that even though I catch a HttpErrorResponse in the final one?

Comment: If you did the same thing in your other interceptors, then your issue isn't in this one ... You need to return the error **everytime**, not just when it suits you.

Comment: Ahah I don't need your upvotes but I know your issue, let me go there